# SQL replace occurrances based on a table

Tags: sql-server

Hi I've a SQL issue to solve; I've these tables:

Table A with varchar column *tst*

**tst**
'2','5','8'
'2','6'
'4','12'

Table B with int column *rep*

**rep**
2
6

I'm looking for a query (without cycle WHILE) to update Table A in the following way:

**tst**
'R','5','8'
'R','R'
'4','12'

using char 'R' to replace the occurrances of Table B in Table A

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your table schema isn't very clear , are these comma separated values?

Comment: Hi, the table A has just one column (varchar): first record contains the string "'2','5','8'" and so on

Comment: This is not simple, but I can think of one way to do it.  About how many values are in the rep column in Table B?

Comment: **You need to redesign your schema**. You should not store "arrays" of strings like this. Instead you need to implement the correct 1:M relationship.

Answer (score 2):

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2bac3/4)

```
UPDATE t1
SET tst = STUFF(z,1,1,'') --Remove leading comma from final result
FROM (
  SELECT --Convert original string to xml
    tst
   ,CAST('<a>'+REPLACE(tst ,',','</a><a>')+'</a>' AS XML) x
  FROM tst
) t1
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT --Replace value with 'R' when matched in rep
    ','+CASE WHEN rep IS NULL THEN y.value('.','varchar(max)') ELSE '''R''' END
  FROM x.nodes('a') t2(y) --Explode xml to separate values
  LEFT JOIN rep t3 --Match value to rep
    ON y.value('.','varchar(max)') = QUOTENAME(rep,CHAR(39))
  FOR XML PATH('') --Recompact xml to comma-delimited string
) t4(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by using a recursive CTE:

```
;with numbers as (
    SELECT 
       rep, 
       -- processing order
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by  rep) working_order 
    FROM B
), worker as (
    -- Anchor: the first substitution
    SELECT 
       tst, 
       rep,
       -- stores already done substitutions  
       replace(tst, '''' + cast(rep as varchar) + '''', '''R''') tmp_result, 
       1 lvl 
    FROM A JOIN numbers ON working_order=1

    UNION ALL

    -- run through all substitutions to be done
    SELECT 
       w.tst, 
       n.rep, 
       -- use tmp_result to refer to already done substitutions
       replace(w.tmp_result, '''' + cast(n.rep as varchar) + '''', '''R'''), 
       lvl + 1 
    FROM worker w JOIN numbers n ON working_order=lvl+1
), result as (
   SELECT tst, tmp_result FROM worker where lvl = (SELECT MAX(working_order) FROM numbers)
)
UPDATE A SET tst=tmp_result FROM A JOIN result ON result.tst=A.tst
```

Explanation:

- First I select all numbers from B and give them a processing number
- In the recursive CTE `worker`, I do a sequential substitution with the
  order given by `numbers`
- In `result` I reduce the worker to the final
  rows (those with the highest `working_order`)
- Finally I update `A` using
  the result.

Comment: Outstanding solution!